Get lat lon values from properties of GeoJSON file
I have several cities boundaries files, all of which contain the center point location of the city in the 'properties' area of the file (INTPTLAT & INTPTLON). How can I extract these values from the two keys.
Here is the basic file structure...
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [ {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "STATEFP": "48",
            "PLACEFP": "20932",
            "PLACENS": "02412441",
            "GEOID": "4820932",
            "NAME": "Dorchester",
            "NAMELSAD": "Dorchester city",
            "LSAD": "25",
            "CLASSFP": "C1",
            "PCICBSA": "N",
            "PCINECTA": "N",
            "MTFCC": "G4110",
            "FUNCSTAT": "A",
            "ALAND": 3390487,
            "AWATER": 0,
            "INTPTLAT": "+33.5312740",
            "INTPTLON": "-096.6890979"},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [

This is how the file is loaded
    let mbAttr  =   'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> | ' +
                                'City Border &copy; <a href="https://public.opendatasoft.com">OpenDataSoft</a> | ' +
                                'Contributor: <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Falke Design</a>',
            mbUrl       =   'https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            twnGeo  =   'assets/geojson/' + geoFile[thisTown] + '.json?v=240930';

    let streets = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, { attribution: mbAttr }),
        twnBorder = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(twnGeo, {style: { color: 'darkgray', weight: 2, fillColor: 'blue' },});

These value are needed to center the L.map("Id", center: [Lat, Lon]...

Please edit your question and add some more code of how you get/load these GeoJSON data and how you use it to create layers.

some translation to numeric - like 33.5312740  ["+33.5312740",] needs to done. see https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/
